# Unprotect all worksheets without password

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to make the below code work on all sheets in my workbook instead of just the active sheet but instead it gets stuck in a loop after the third worksheet.

I think maybe what's happening is that there are hidden worksheets in this workbook that are  making it fail. If I could just unprotect visible worksheets that would maybe solve it? I tried that as well though, but I don't think my logic is correct and I don't think it's worth sharing.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated

My edits:

```
Sub UnprotectAllSheets()
         Dim WS_Count As Integer
         Dim WsNum As Integer
         WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
         For WsNum = 1 To WS_Count
            Dim I As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
            Dim l As Integer, m As Integer, n As Integer
            Dim i1 As Integer, i2 As Integer, i3 As Integer
            Dim i4 As Integer, i5 As Integer, i6 As Integer
            On Error Resume Next
            For I = 65 To 66: For j = 65 To 66: For k = 65 To 66
            For l = 65 To 66: For m = 65 To 66: For i1 = 65 To 66
            For i2 = 65 To 66: For i3 = 65 To 66: For i4 = 65 To 66
            For i5 = 65 To 66: For i6 = 65 To 66: For n = 32 To 126
            Worksheets(WsNum).Unprotect Chr(I) & Chr(j) & Chr(k) & _
                Chr(l) & Chr(m) & Chr(i1) & Chr(i2) & Chr(i3) & _
                Chr(i4) & Chr(i5) & Chr(i6) & Chr(n)
            If Worksheets(WsNum).ProtectContents = False Then
                GoTo NextSht
            End If
            Next: Next: Next: Next: Next: Next
            Next: Next: Next: Next: Next: Next
NextSht:
         Next WsNum

      End Sub
```

Original code:

```
Sub PasswordBreaker()
'Breaks worksheet password protection.

    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
    Dim l As Integer, m As Integer, n As Integer
    Dim i1 As Integer, i2 As Integer, i3 As Integer
    Dim i4 As Integer, i5 As Integer, i6 As Integer
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 65 To 66: For j = 65 To 66: For k = 65 To 66
    For l = 65 To 66: For m = 65 To 66: For i1 = 65 To 66
    For i2 = 65 To 66: For i3 = 65 To 66: For i4 = 65 To 66
    For i5 = 65 To 66: For i6 = 65 To 66: For n = 32 To 126
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Chr(i) & Chr(j) & Chr(k) & _
        Chr(l) & Chr(m) & Chr(i1) & Chr(i2) & Chr(i3) & _
        Chr(i4) & Chr(i5) & Chr(i6) & Chr(n)
    If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents = False Then
        MsgBox "One usable password is " & Chr(i) & Chr(j) & _
            Chr(k) & Chr(l) & Chr(m) & Chr(i1) & Chr(i2) & _
            Chr(i3) & Chr(i4) & Chr(i5) & Chr(i6) & Chr(n)
         Exit Sub
    End If
    Next: Next: Next: Next: Next: Next
    Next: Next: Next: Next: Next: Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually it was the visible worksheet problem I said earlier that would fix it. I got it with Activate sheets but not sure why simply doing `Worksheets(wsnum).Unprotect` doesn't work... alas, here's the code:

```
Sub passwordbreaker()
    Dim WS_Count As Integer
    Dim wsnum As Integer
    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    For wsnum = 1 To WS_Count
        If Worksheets(wsnum).Visible = True Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(wsnum).Activate
            Dim I As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
            Dim l As Integer, m As Integer, n As Integer
            Dim i1 As Integer, i2 As Integer, i3 As Integer
            Dim i4 As Integer, i5 As Integer, i6 As Integer
            On Error Resume Next
            For I = 65 To 66: For j = 65 To 66: For k = 65 To 66
            For l = 65 To 66: For m = 65 To 66: For i1 = 65 To 66
            For i2 = 65 To 66: For i3 = 65 To 66: For i4 = 65 To 66
            For i5 = 65 To 66: For i6 = 65 To 66: For n = 32 To 126
            ActiveSheet.Unprotect Chr(I) & Chr(j) & Chr(k) & _
                Chr(l) & Chr(m) & Chr(i1) & Chr(i2) & Chr(i3) & _
                Chr(i4) & Chr(i5) & Chr(i6) & Chr(n)
            If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents = False Then
                 GoTo nextsht
            End If
            Next: Next: Next: Next: Next: Next
            Next: Next: Next: Next: Next: Next
        End If
nextsht:
    Next wsnum
End Sub
```