# Why will the code work when i activate sheets but not when I don't?

Tags: excel, vba

As shown below, if I add the ws.Activate this code runs great, but if I don't then it gets stuck in endless loop around the ws.unprotect. Why is that? Is there any way to make this code run without having to activate each sheet?

```
Sub passwordbreaker()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Visible = True Then
```

**`ws.Activate`**

```
            Dim I As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
            Dim l As Integer, m As Integer, n As Integer
            Dim i1 As Integer, i2 As Integer, i3 As Integer
            Dim i4 As Integer, i5 As Integer, i6 As Integer
            On Error Resume Next
            For I = 65 To 66: For j = 65 To 66: For k = 65 To 66
            For l = 65 To 66: For m = 65 To 66: For i1 = 65 To 66
            For i2 = 65 To 66: For i3 = 65 To 66: For i4 = 65 To 66
            For i5 = 65 To 66: For i6 = 65 To 66: For n = 32 To 126
            ws.Unprotect Chr(I) & Chr(j) & Chr(k) & _
                Chr(l) & Chr(m) & Chr(i1) & Chr(i2) & Chr(i3) & _
                Chr(i4) & Chr(i5) & Chr(i6) & Chr(n)
            If ws.ProtectContents = False Then
                 GoTo nextsht
            End If
            Next: Next: Next: Next: Next: Next
            Next: Next: Next: Next: Next: Next
        End If
nextsht:
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unprotect all worksheets without password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58165818/unprotect-all-worksheets-without-password)

Comment: What errors in your code are you wanting to ignore?